# Bootstrap tooltip is not working on *ngIf

Tags: angular, tooltip

I have following code in HTML file

```
<div class="col-md-10" *ngIf="isEdit">
   <input type="text" maxlength="255" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Optional description of the Plan" class="form-control">
</div>
```

tooltip is not showing if i hover on input box, if I remove *ngIf="isEdit" then it is showing the tooltip

Comment: Try `[hidden]` instead of `ngIf`

Answer (score 0):

Set `isEdit` to `true` inside your TS file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solve it implementing `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`